# Using sql importer, how can I import schema details like PK/FK?

Tags: sql-server

I did a sql import (sql08) and it didn't import PK/FK type information.

It only transfered data and created the tables.

How can I make it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCript the tables including scripting indexes, constraints, foreign keys etc.

Run the script then use the wizard to transfer the data into the new empty table using append rather thant create.

You could also using the wizard click on Edit mappings (onthe Select Source Tables and Views page) and then edit SQl and add the code for those things yourself to the table definition script.